# producer & consumer - multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a multithreading program like this,

```
#include <queue>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mu = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t ec = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t fc = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

queue<int> qu;
const int N = 2;

void *producer(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);
        int tmp = rand();
        qu.push(tmp);
        pthread_cond_signal(&ec);
        if ((int) qu.size() > N) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&fc, &mu);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu);
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);
        if ((int) qu.size() < 1) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&ec, &mu);
        }
        int tmp = qu.front();
        qu.pop();
        if ((int) qu.size() <= N) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&fc);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu);
        //sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, producer, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    }

    printf("all created\n");

    sleep(600);
}
```

When the `qu.size()` is geater than `N`, `producer` should stop producing, and when it's less than `N`, `producer` resumes producing.

The weired problem is, if I remove the `sleep(1);` in `consumer`, the program will run into `segmentation fault`, if I keep `sleep(1);`, the program runs ok.

Why? Does it mean the `consumer` consumes too fast?

Comment: @AntoineMathys, ok, I'm posting my complete code.

Comment: @Antoine Mathys: it's multithreading, just because it was working for you doesn't mean that the code is correct.

Comment: Your functions should end with `return` statements and your `main` shouldn't sleep, but `join` all of the threads that are created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spurious wakeup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) might be the reason. Your thread will proceed if the condition is true, but if your thread proceeds you can't assume the condition is true.

> Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() functions may occur. Since the return from pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

So for example

```
if (qu.size() == 0) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&ec, &mu);
}
```

should become

```
while (qu.size() == 0) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&ec, &mu);
}
```

Comment: By `while(qu.size() == 0)`, you are re-evaluating the `qu.size() == 0` to make sure its size is indeed 0, right?\

Comment: You make sure you don't go to the next step if the queue is empty. basically you check whether there's really something to process or you just experienced a spurious wakeup

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, that means `pthread_cond_wait` may wakeup even if `ec` has bot been signaled, right?

Comment: Using `while`, my program works, :-). I kinda feel it's not safe to use pthread_cond_wait

Comment: It's safe to use it, it's just not safe to misuse it. The `pthread_cond_wait` function is completely stateless -- it is your obligation to maintain and check the state associated with whatever you are waiting for. While one consumer is waking up, another consumer could empty the queue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, but I use mutex to make sure that only one consumer could pop the queue, so how could the scenario that "While one consumer is waking up, another consumer could empty the queue" can happen?

Comment: @Alcott: While you are waking up, you do not hold the mutex. The whole point of `pthread_cond_wait` is to sleep with the mutex released.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, then after I wake up, should I `pthread_mutex_lock` the mutex before I proceed?

Comment: @Alcott: No. It is re-acquired for you. That's part of the semantics of `pthread_cond_wait`.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the `sleep(1)` call and the whole thing does not crash you're just lucky :)

Try initializing the mutex explicitly using the pthread_mutex_init() otherwise your pthread_mutex_lock() calls seem to fail.

From [the docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock):

```
Errors

The pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_trylock()
functions may fail if: 

EINVAL: The value specified by mutex
does not refer to an initialized mutex object.
```